# Findelement in selenium and retain value in json page

Tags: javascript, selenium

I know there has been a several threads regarding the same question, but none of them worked for me. I have two questions.

1. Is there any other way to get the element other than using `xpath`, as I am using the below code to select the line number 9 in the json page, what if the line number changes in a new page. So I want to get the value by some other way.

   ```
   WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//[@id='aceEditor']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[9]/div/span[2]"));
   ```
2. I am updating the double quoted string in line 9(Test_Password) , It is a password and I am changing it using Javascript using below code. Though the value is updated , after a page refresh the value is getting changed to the original value. It is a password and after setting when I go and login with the new password I am not able to do that. I want the values to remain same even after page refresh. Please help me with the code.

**Javascript I use:**

```
WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aceEditor']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[9]/div/span[2]"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver1).executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = '"+ replace_text + "'", ele);
```

HTML Code:
`<div class="ace_line" style="height:14px">&nbsp;&nbsp;<span` `class="ace_variable">"value"</span>:&nbsp;<span` `class="ace_string">"Test_password"</span>,</div>`

[image: jsonpage]

Comment: 1. You can use `CSS` selector or replace absolute `XPath`with relative `//span[text()="Test_password"]` as it more reliable and flexible. 2. Hard to understand this question :)

Comment: Actually you can modify element inner text at runtime which would be effected for the same execution at same page, this value would neither be stored anywhere to show at the next time during page refresh nor perform any action. So this is not possible..

Comment: Thankyou, but there are so many ace_strings under the same class.How should i locate the password, is it possible for me to use ace_variable and get the value of ace_string?

Comment: As the "test_Password" will not be the only value everytime.

Comment: Hi Andersson , my second question is about retaining an updated value even after the page is refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to get the element other than using `xpath`

Yes, there is other way instead of using `xpath` to get the same element. You should try using `By.cssSelector()` as below :-

```
WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ace_string"));
```

Or

```
WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("#aceEditor span.ace_string"));
```

Or using `By.className()` it this element has unique class name as below :-

```
WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.className("ace_string"));
```

> I want the values to remain same even after page refresh.

No, you can't achieve this. Actually it just happens at runtime. You're just temporary changing inner text of the element which wouldn't be effected to change the actual content forever unless you can perform some action to update password which to be store into DB or other place for the backup which will see effect later.

Comment: Hi saurabh, If i change the value manually and click on update the value is retained even after page refresh. It is not retaining only when i change it through javascript.

Comment: @Lavanya So when you are going to change manually, where do you enter the text and where do you perform the click??

Comment: I will jus open the link, go to line 9 and replace the password value as required and click on 'update' button . Now the value retains even after refreshing the page. But when i change the password value using the javascipt code above it changes the value, clicks the update button, but after refresh the value is not retained.

Comment: So you should try using `sendKeys` at password field after getting that element instead of changing their textContent, then click on update button this would defenetely work ..

Comment: I have tried as below and getting this exception **invalid element state: Element is not currently interactable and may not be manipulated**                  `WebElement ele = driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='aceEditor']/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[9]/div/span[2]"));
ele.clear();
ele.sendKeys("my_password");`

Comment: So exception clearly states this element can not be manipulated. I think you are working on incorrect element, you need to verify which element can manipulated..

Comment: Or if this correct element try to `.click()` on it before `.sendKeys()` may it helps..:)

Comment: Hi , It is a Json script, given few lines of it in my question. So if i try to click the control is on the whole script rather than on the specific line where i have to. So send keys doesnt work. But i am able to replace it using javascript, the problem is it doesnt retain.